# WebGL not showing images at startup

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have programmed a WebGL-React-App which should load 4 planes with 4 images when i import a file. When i import the file all planes are blue, and the images are only loaded if i move the view. How can i manage that the images are loaded right after file import? I have read several similar problems which are solved with "Promise", but a had not luck transfer it to my code.

Here is my code:

```
export function createLabel(gl, desc) {

console.log("create label: " + desc);

let coords = buildQuadricTriangleStrip(0.5);
let texture = null;

if (desc === DESC.N) {
    coords = translateQuad(coords, 0.5, -0.25, 0);
    texture = loadTexture(gl, "/images/n.png");
}

if (desc === DESC.S) {
    coords = rotateQuad(coords, ROT_AXIS.Z, 180);
    coords = translateQuad(coords, -0.5, 0.25, 0);
    texture = loadTexture(gl, "/images/s.png");
}

if (desc === DESC.E) {
    coords = rotateQuad(coords, ROT_AXIS.Z, 180);
    //coords = rotateQuad(coords, ROT_AXIS.Z, 180);
    coords = translateQuad(coords, 0.25, -0.5, 0);
    texture = loadTexture(gl, "/images/e.png");
}

if (desc === DESC.W) {
    coords = rotateQuad(coords, ROT_AXIS.Z, 180);
    coords = translateQuad(coords, 0.25, 1, 0);
    texture = loadTexture(gl, "/images/w.png");
}

//console.log(texture);

const textureCoordinates = [
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0
]

const indices = [
    2, 3, 1,
    0, 1, 2
]

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(coords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const textureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordinates), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let vs = document.getElementById("vshaderlabel").textContent;
let fs = document.getElementById("fshaderlabel").textContent;

const shaderProgram = shader.initShaderProgram(gl, vs, fs);

const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
        vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition"),
        textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aTextureCoord'),
    },
    uniformLocations: {
        projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uProjectionMatrix"),
        modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uModelViewMatrix"),
        uSampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uSampler'),
    },
};

return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    textureCoord: textureCoordBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
    positionSize: coords.length,
    texture,
    programInfo
};
}

 function loadTexture(gl, url) {
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

const level = 0;
const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
const width = 1;
const height = 1;
const border = 0;
const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]); // opaque blue

gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    width,
    height,
    border,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    pixel,
);

const image = new Image();

image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,
        level,
        internalFormat,
        srcFormat,
        srcType,
        image,
    );

    // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images
    // vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
    // power of 2 in both dimensions.
    if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
        // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
        // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn off mips and set
        // wrapping to clamp to edge
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    }
});
image.src = url;

return texture;
 }

 function isPowerOf2(value) {
return (value & (value - 1)) === 0;
 }

export function draw(gl, projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, buffers) {
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(buffers.programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(buffers.programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.textureCoord);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(buffers.programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(buffers.programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.indices);

gl.useProgram(buffers.programInfo.program);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    buffers.programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
    false,
    projectionMatrix
);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    buffers.programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
    false,
    modelViewMatrix
);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
// Bind the texture to texture unit 0
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, buffers.texture);
// Tell the shader we bound the texture to texture unit 0
gl.uniform1i(buffers.programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);

//gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, buffers.positionSize / 3);
{
    const vertexCount = buffers.positionSize / 2;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);
}
}
```

Comment: From your explanation, it sounds like `draw()` is performed before the images are loaded. If you don't want to continuously `draw()`, then you could issue a redraw on the image load event

Comment: CreateLabel should be called only once. Draw is continously called if i move the 3d object. Createlabel doesnt know the matrices...

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there no one who could help me?

Comment: I already gave an educated guess. When the `load` even listener is called, you need to ensure that `draw()` is called again